# Obtaining Profile Photo from MS Graph API to Angular app

Tags: angular, azure, api

I am new to angular and I am trying to call Microsoft Graph API from my Angular app to display profile photo from Microsoft account. The authentication process performs by using Azure AD.

environment.ts

```
 azure: {
    tenantId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
    applicationId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
    endpoint: {
      root: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0',
      profile: '/me',
      profilePhoto: '/me/photo'
    },
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200'
  }
```

I've developed a code to authenticate the get the profile photo from API. below is my

profile.component.ts

```
get_profile_photo() {
    this.msg.getProfilePhoto().subscribe(
      (response) => {
        console.log('get_profile_photo() success');
        console.log(response);
        this.profilePhoto = response;
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error("Error getting MS Graph Profile \n" + JSON.stringify(error));
        throw (error);
      }
    )
  }
```

This will call to

ms-graph.service.ts

```
getProfilePhoto() {
    return this.httpClient.get<ProfilePhoto>(
        env.azure.endpoint.root+'/me/photo'
    );
}
```

After then I've got success response as below

{@odata.context: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('…a69c7-94ad-49ad-8d5d-xxxxxxxxxxxx')/photo/$entity",
@odata.mediaContentType: "image/jpeg",
@odata.mediaEtag: "W/"94777476813e1400e64bca040592df3b92f1ec7c2baxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"", id: "648x648", height: 648, …}

But this needs to convert to base64 before passing URL to src="" attributes.
I referred to many tutorials from the web and was unable to convert them.

Then I tried the below method to get a profile photo from the MS account using the above authentications.

ms-graph.service.ts

```
getImage(imageUrl: string): Observable<File> {
    return this.http
      .get(imageUrl, {responseType: 'blob'})
      .map((res: Response) => res.blob);
  }
```

my ts code is like this on second option

profile.component.ts

```
 createImageFromBlob(image: Blob) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
      this.imageToShow = reader.result;
      console.log(this.imageToShow);
      return this.imageToShow;
    }, false);
    if (image) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(image);
    }
  }
  get_profile_photo() {
    this.isImageLoading = true;
    this.imageService.getImage('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo').subscribe(data => {
      this.createImageFromBlob(data);
      this.isImageLoading = false;
    }, error => {
      this.isImageLoading = false;
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
```

Then I've got the below error from this.

```
core.js:6479 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at ImageService.getImage (image.service.ts:12)
    at ProfileComponent.get_profile_photo (profile.component.ts:65)
    at ProfileComponent_Template_button_click_23_listener (profile.component.html:15)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:15308)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:15346)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:560)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28659)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178)
```

Anybody can help with me this to figure this issue and get profile photo from MS account?

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue and just getting working fine. So, sharing here my experience. It helps others.

According to official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0#using-the-binary-data-of-the-requested-photo), there is no end to end example.

Here is my

> profile.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpClient,
  HttpErrorResponse,
  HttpHeaders,
  HttpResponse,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class ProfileService implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  getImage(imageUrl: string): Observable<Blob> {
    return this.http
      .get(imageUrl, {
        responseType: 'blob',
        headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg' }),
      })
      .pipe(
        map((res: any) => {
          return res;
        })
      );
  }
}
```

> profile.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injector, OnDestroy, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { UserProfileService } from './user-profile.service';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

const GRAPH_ENDPOINT_GET_PHOTO =
  'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  providers: [ProfileService],
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit
{

  isImageLoading: boolean = false;
  imageToShow: any;

  constructor(
    private _profileService: ProfileService,
    private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
     // To get user's photo
     this.getProfilePicture();();
  }

  getProfilePicture() {
    this.isImageLoading = true;
    this._profileService.getImage(GRAPH_ENDPOINT_GET_PHOTO).subscribe(
      (blob) => {
        this.isImageLoading = false;

        var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        this.imageToShow = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(
          urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob)
        );
      },
      (error) => {
        this.isImageLoading = false;
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

  createImageFromBlob(image: Blob) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener(
      'load',
      () => {
        console.log(reader.result);
        const imgRes: any = reader.result;
        this.imageToShow = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(imgRes);
      },
      false
    );
    if (image) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(image);
    }
  }

}
```

and final

> profile.component.html

```
<div class="container">
<img
  [src]="imageToShow"
  alt="Place image title" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='./assets/images/user_placeholder_img.jpg';"
  *ngIf="!isImageLoading; else noImageFound"
/>
<ng-template #noImageFound>
  <img
    src="./assets/images/user_placeholder_img.jpg"
    alt="Fallbackimage"
  />
</ng-template>
</div>
```

> Note: Here Authorization Bearer token I'm using via MSALInterceptorConfigFactory.

Comment: I have two questions. 1) Why in your profileService you have the code `ngOnInit`. 2) The method `createImageFromBlob(image: Blob) `, I don't see how it is used. Thanks

Comment: This really helped me out a lot. There are several changes that should be made though. 
1. this.getProfilePicture(); has one too many (); on the end
2. createImageFromBlob is not needed and can be scrapped
3. the subscribe method needs to be updated to the next, error, complete which will allow you to put isImageLoading = true in the next, and isImageLoading = false in the complete

Answer (score 1):

To get the profile photo data in binary format, the endpoint URL should be `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value`. `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo` returns the metadata about the profile photo and not the content.

I am not familiar with Angular but this is the code I wrote sometime back to fetch profile photo content. Please note that this code is plain JavaScript.

```
axios.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value', {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
    },
    responseType: 'blob'
})
.then((response) => {
    const url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    const blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
    //You can use this blobUrl as src value in img tag.
}
```

Comment: I've got an error of "Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Observable<Blob>" by executing this code. What is the reason for it? also, what is the "axios" here? Another thing is, accessing the URL from component is not good practice while we can access through the service.

Comment: Like I said in my answer, I am not familiar with Angular so I wrote this JS code in my application. You would need to convert this code to Angular. `axios` is the library to make HTTP requests.