# User profile enrichment in AZUREAD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have a question regarding user profile enrichment.
How can I enrich a user profile with extra information such as id-number, personal telephone, and any other information available in my office356 platform?

I have an Angular SPA in which the user must log in and subsequently do some actions, but I do require to get the info mentioned before in order to do so.

I have code like the showed below. I've searched into Azure's documentation but found nothing yet.

```
const GRAPH_ENDPOINT = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me';

  getProfile() {
    this.http.get(GRAPH_ENDPOINT)
      .subscribe(profile => {
        this.profile = profile;
        console.log(profile)
      });
  }

  getProfilePhoto() {
    this.http.get(GRAPH_ENDPOINT+'/photo/$value').subscribe(
      photo => { 
        this.photo = photo; 
        console.log(this.photo);
    });
  }
```

Any help or tip to help this poor fellow programmer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please check this if query for id or mobile number  etc can be worked for  the similar code, if am not understating wrong:

As 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me  gives complete profile details just like code provided

> ```
> const GRAPH_ENDPOINT = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me';
>
>   getProfile() {
>     this.http.get(GRAPH_ENDPOINT)
>       .subscribe(profile => {
>         this.profile = profile;
>         console.log(profile)
>       });
>   }
> ```

same in microsoft graph api :

[image]

Just like that we can query for id, mobilephone number, and other details
By filtering using select query
See References for more query parameters: [Get a user-Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs -REFERENCE](http://Get%20a%20user%20-%20Microsoft%20Graph%20v1.0%20%7C%20Microsoft%20Docs)  , [Use query parameters](http://Use%20query%20parameters%20to%20customize%20responses%20-%20Microsoft%20Graph%20%7C%20Microsoft%20Docs)

[image]

So to get mobilenumber in graph https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=mobilePhone is used, same can be modified for code some thing like below
Example:

```
 getMobileNumber() {
    this.http.get(GRAPH_ENDPOINT+'?$select=mobilePhone ').subscribe(
      mobilePhone => { 
        this. mobilePhone = mobilePhone; 
        console.log( this. mobilePhone);
    });
  }
```

Just like from graph
[image]

So to get id in graph https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=id ,modify your code which uses this request.

Example:

```
getId(){
this.http.get(GRAPH_ENDPOINT+'?$select=id ').subscribe(
      Id=> { 
        this. Id= Id; 
        console.log( this. Id);

});
}
```

You can also make use of graph client

**References:**

1. [Build Angular single-page apps with Microsoft Graph - Microsoft
   Graph | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/angular?tutorial-step=3)
2. [azure - Obtaining Profile Photo from MS Graph API to Angular app -
   Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68834838/obtaining-profile-photo-from-ms-graph-api-to-angular-app)  from >> [So reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35600691/how-to-get-users-image-using-microsoft-graph-api-encoding-issue)
3. [create-requests-typescript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-requests?tabs=TypeScript)

Comment: I'll check it later and let you know how it went. 
Hope it helps.

Thank you!